# The sortable element helper is undefined using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Heres the code:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

<%= sortable_element("property-sort", :url => "hello") %>
```

I want to implement drag-and-drop sorting in Rails. I am following the [Railscast on sortable lists](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists). I got the error from this line `<%= sortable_element("property-sort", :url => "hello") %>` which tells it is undefined.

Comment: That tutorial is from 2009. You shouldn't be using it, it will never work with modern versions of Rails.

Comment: can you give a tutorial link that is compatible to rails 4

Comment: There are many out there. I have none to recommend, and asking for recommendations for tutorials or other off-site resources is off-topic on this website.

Answer (score 3):

`sortable_element` is a helper method for the Prototype JS library which was removed from Rails in version 3.1.  Rails dropped Prototype in favor of jQuery back in 2011.

That Railscasts episode uses an old version of Rails with Prototype. The tutorial took advantage of Prototype helper methods (such as `sortable_element`) which are no longer included in modern Rails versions.

---

You can still get sortable lists with jQueryUI. Install the [`jquery-ui-rails` gem](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) and follow the instructions for adding the necessary [JS](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails#interactions) and [CSS](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails#interactions-1) assets for the `sortable` interaction.

See the jQueryUI [examples](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) and [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) for help with coding your views.